# Why is there a Weak References Between Managed Objects and the Context?

Tags: ios, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

When i was learning how to use child contexts :

```
 let childContext =
 NSManagedObjectContext(
concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
 childContext.parent = coreDataStack.mainContext

let childEntry =
childContext.object(with: surfJournalEntry.objectID)
as? JournalEntry
 // 3
detailViewController.journalEntry = childEntry
detailViewController.context = childContext
detailViewController.delegate = self
```

Author made some remark about passing both  managed object and the managed object context to the detailViewController:

> Note: You might be wondering why you need to pass both the managed
>   object and the managed object context to the detailViewController,
>   since managed objects already have a context variable. This is because
>   managed objects only have a weak reference to the context. If you
>   don’t pass the context, ARC will remove the context from memory (since
>   nothing else is retaining it) and the app will not behave as you
>   expect.

Well, ok, so then a read some official doc:

> This means that in general you cannot rely on a context to ensure the
>   longevity of a managed object instance, and you cannot rely on the
>   existence of a managed object to ensure the longevity of a context.
>   Put another way, just because you fetched an object doesn’t mean it
>   will stay around.

But yet, i don't get what is true intention of making  weak references between managed objects and the context? What is the goal do they pursue?

Comment: What is "some official doc"? It would help if this quote could be read in context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed object contexts *usually* use weak references to fetched objects to avoid the potential for excessive memory use. If it used strong references, and you did one or more fetches that found a large number of results, all of them would remain in memory for as long as the context existed. In many apps that would mean they'd never go away, because the context exists until the app exits. That could cause the app to use a lot of memory for objects it wasn't using anymore. Weak references mean that the managed objects are deallocated as soon as the app stops using them.

But you might want strong references in some cases, so there's a boolean property called `retainsRegisteredObjects` that makes the context use strong references instead. Use it if you like, but be careful of memory use.

Managed objects don't keep strong references to their contexts to avoid reference cycles. If they were strong references and you set `retainsRegisteredObjects` to `true`, you'd get a reference cycle. Each object would hold a strong reference to the other, so neither could be released from memory unless you set one of the references to nil.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of managedObject as small and stupid object.  They have a pointer to their context and know their objectId.  When they need to know something they query the context.  This has a lot of really neat advantages.  If an entity was already queried in the context, a second instance of it will hit the row cache in the context and not hit the store at all.

Generally there are two kinds of context (for most core data setups): long lived main queue context that are always in memory, and short lived background contexts. For the main queue context you generally don't need to worry about the contexts leaving memory.  They stay in memory for the lifetime of the application. The short lived context have a problem of leaving memory and also have a problem that they are not thread-safe. So generally they should be created in a block that is on the correct thread - used and then discarded and not pass out of the block.

I hope that explains it.